# redirecting to root, even if query is empty

Tags: nginx, lumen

All my links is redirecting to root, where I serve the file "index.php".

This is my nginx config : 
/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject.local

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 444 ssl http2;
    server_name .buildurlshortener.local;
    root "/home/vagrant/codecourse/buildurlshortener/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/buildurlshortener.local-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/buildurlshortener.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/buildurlshortener.local.key;
}
```

If I make a post request to "http://myproject.local/something", it works.

But a post request to the root, i.e. http://myproject.local, is not working.
I get "405 Not Allowed" from nginx.

If I add a rule with "location ~ { ... }", then I can post to "http://myproject.local".  But now it is "http://myproject.local/something" that is not working.

How can I also serve "index.php" from the root ("/"), without breaking my other routes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this line :

location ~ .php$

I appended `|/$` :

location ~ .php$|/$

So that it can also accept an empty query.

Now I can use post requests to  "myproject.local", "myproject.local/index.php", ""myproject.local/someroute".

Answer (score 0):

One of the causes of message "405 Not Allowed" is that nginx can't serve static content on POST-request. Could you show config more detailed?

Comment: Is there any index.html or index.htm file into documents root folder?

Comment: Oh just found a solution : `location ~ \.php$|/$`

Comment: I think string ```index index.html index.htm index.php;``` have to be ```index index.php index.html index.htm;```

Comment: but your solution is ok

Comment: I've tried that string, not working.  Thanks for helping !